# ajax get file size

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to create a custom ajax upload for a project .
therefore dont want to use some open source scripts/codes.
 So Here's the situation
im trying to get upload size of the file using jquery ajax while the file is uploading by fetching file size of the file from a php file.
So i'll use .delay() to repeat process after a certain interval and '$_FILES['file'] ['tmp_name'] ' to fetch its name and size etc ..
can any body help me on how to do this ???
im a bit confused ..

Comment: This makes no sense: The $_FILES array will be populated before the PHP script starts running. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: why do you need filesize on the client side?

Comment: To show that 'x' amount is upload out of 'xx' amount

Comment: I want to fetch the size of the file while uploading

Comment: Already awnsered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455282/call-a-javascript-function-at-a-specific-time-of-day

Answer (score 1):

With a standard install of PHP, you will not be able to track the upload of a file : once the upload is complete, you'll be able to work with `$_FILES` ; but not as long as the upload is in progress.

If you want to keep track of the progress of an upload, you'll have to either :

- Install the [**APC extension**](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC), and configure [**`apc.rfc1867`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.rfc1867) *(there are a bit more informations on that page)*
- Install the [**uploadprogress**](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress/) extension, which has been created to do just that.

Here are a couple of articles that might give you some pointers :

- APC : [Monitoring File Uploads using Ajax and PHP](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/php-ajax-file-uploads)
- [Upload Progress Meter - Common issues and some answers](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2009/03/31/upload-progress-meter-common-issues-and-some-answers.html)
- [Upload Progress Meter extension for PHP 5.2](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2006/09/10/upload-progress-meter-extension-for-php-5-2.html)
- [AJAX File upload Progress](http://blog.joshuaeichorn.com/archives/2005/05/01/ajax-file-upload-progress/) and [PHP AJAX File Upload Progress Meter Updates](http://blog.joshuaeichorn.com/archives/2006/03/14/php-ajax-file-upload-progress-meter-updates/)

From what I recall, when it comes to tracking files uploads, the second solution might be a better choice -- if I'm not mistaken, APC stores more stuff in RAM, which could cause some problems.

And here's a question+answer about that specific matter : [**APC vs pecl uploadprogress**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939271/apc-vs-pecl-uploadprogress)

Comment: cant we do it without can other mods etc... in pure jquery or php?

Comment: With PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3, no, that's not something that can be done using PHP itself *(not adding any extension, I mean)* ;;; With the next version of PHP *(might be called 5.4, maybe)*, it might be possible, see http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/151-Upload-Progress-in-PHP-trunk.html